# System of Linear Equations with a Separable Solution

Tags: linear-algebra, finite-fields

I reduced a problem I was working on to determining whether a system of linear of equations over $GF(2)$ has a separable solution. I was wondering what would be the most efficient way of deciding this.

Given $A \in \mathbb{Z}_2^{nm} \times  \mathbb{Z}_2^{nm}$, and $\textbf{b} \in \mathbb{Z}_2^{nm}$,  is there a poly-time algorithm to decide whether there are some $\textbf{x} \in \mathbb{Z}_2^{n}$ and $\textbf{y} \in \mathbb{Z}_2^{m}$ such that $A(\textbf{x} \otimes \textbf{y}) = \textbf{b}$?

I know how to do it when $A$ is invertible, but if not, it's not clear to me how one could check exponentially many cases in polynomial time.

P.S. I tried to find a related result in the literature, but I couldn't find it, probably because I'm not quite familiar with the terminology. I'm sorry if this is a trivial question.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE, hope you stay around and contribute to the site.

Comment: Thank you very much :))

Comment: This is probably a side question, but assuming that such a poly-time algorithm existed and provided a candidate $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}$.  Is it a poly-time algorithm that would verify these are valid solutions?  Just curious as to the complexity class of the algorithms in question.  Thanks.

Comment: @ad2004 Yes; it's easy to check whether a vector $v$ is a simple tensor product, i.e. whether it can be written in the form $v = x \otimes y$.  In particular, $v$ is a simple tensor if and only if $\operatorname{vec}^{-1}(v)$ is a rank-1 matrix (where vec denotes the [vectorization operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)).

Comment: @TheBadPlus we could equivalently frame this problem over matrices.  Given any [affine subspace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_space) $S \subset \Bbb Z_2^{m \times n}$, the question is whether there exists an $M \in S$ such that the rank of $M$ is $1$.

Comment: @TheBadPlus In general, the problem of finding a low-rank element of an affine subspace is difficult to solve.  For instance, the sub-problem of matrix completion with a given rank is generally believed not to have a poly-time algorithm. That being said, most work in this area is done over $\Bbb R$ or $\Bbb C$; I don't know if working over a finite field makes things much easier.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Thanks for the clarification.  The algorithm to discover the solution sounds like it might be formally equivalent to an NP-complete problem.  Perhaps this has already been established based on your comments regarding the complexity of the matrix completion sub-problem.  Thanks again.

Comment: Following up on @Omnomnomnom's train of thought. The set of matrices of rank 1 is defined by the vanishing of quadratic polynomials (the 2x2 minors). Thus the set of  solutions in the $mn$ binary variables can be defined by quadratic polynomials. We can constrain the variables to $\Bbb{Z}_2$ by declaring more quadratic equations $x_{ij}^2=x_{ij}$. In theory finding  Gröbner basis should lead to a solution of the decision problem. I'm not at all conversant with this theory. May be the problem is that when doing that the number of equations blows up?

Comment: It may be an instance of a notorious [boolean satisfability problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_satisfiability_problem), but I don't understand that theory at all. It may turn out that all the polynomials being quadratic is a special case?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen is there a straightforward way to solve an arbitrary system of quadratic equations?

Comment: I don't now of one @Omnomnomnom. I brought that up to suggest that we may be outside the scope of the results stating that boolean satisfiability is in some nasty NP class.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Oh I guess I misunderstood your point, thanks for clarifying